# Hot do i set text colour to all radio buttons in all radio groups in Android

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop

I am trying to set all radio buttons from all radio groups enable and text color red. When i use `radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setEnabled(true);` it works but when i use `radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setTextColor(Color.RED);` doesn't work. How can i set the red colour to all radio button from all radio groups?
The second problem is when i check a radio button from a radio group and i use `radioGroup[i].clearCheck();` the the first radio button remains always checked. How can i clearCheck all radio buttons?
Here is my code:

```
    finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                radioGroup[i].clearCheck();
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setEnabled(true); // works
                    radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setTextColor(Color.RED); // doesn't work
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for both problems. Here is the code:

```
finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            radioGroup[i].clearCheck();
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setEnabled(true);
                ((RadioButton)radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j)).setTextColor(Color.RED);
                ((RadioButton)radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j)).setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }
});
```